# read data slow for large database in firebase in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase for my Chating app. I store all information about the user from there. Normally if Firebase database does not have large data it gives a quick response. But once data is an increase in the database it becomes too slow. The same database is working perfectly on my android app. Please help me with solving this issue.

I am using the following method for fetching data from firebase.

```
-(void) get_grouplist_refresh_single{

    @try{
        appDel.totalUnreadMsg = 0;
        [[FIRDatabase database] goOnline];
        FIRDatabaseReference *rootRef= [[FIRDatabase database] referenceWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/users/%@/activeGroups",appDel.UserId]];
        [rootRef  observeSingleEventOfType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {
            //NSLog(@"group: %@", snapshot.value);
            if ([snapshot exists]) {

                NSDictionary *postDict = snapshot.value;
                NSArray *key_dictionary=[postDict allKeys];
                if (key_dictionary.count > 0) {
                    for (int i=0; i < key_dictionary.count; i++) {
                        [self set_listner_group :[key_dictionary objectAtIndex:i]];
                        [self load_all_active_groupmsg :[key_dictionary objectAtIndex:i]];
                        if(key_dictionary.count - 1 == i){

                        }

                    }
                }else{

                }
            }else{
                [[FIRDatabase database] goOnline];
            }

        }];
    } @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"NSException %@",exception);
    } @finally {

    }
     }

-(void) set_listner_group :(NSString*) strGroupId{

    @try{
        FIRDatabaseReference *rootRef= [[FIRDatabase database] referenceWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/groups/%@",strGroupId]];
        [rootRef  observeSingleEventOfType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {
            if ([snapshot exists]) {
                //Do somthing base on requirements
            }

        }];
    } @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"NSException %@",exception);
    } @finally {

    }
}
-(void) load_all_active_groupmsg :(NSString*)strgroupID{

    FIRDatabaseHandle handlerLoadAllMsg = 0;
    FIRDatabaseReference *rootRef= [[FIRDatabase database] referenceWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/group_msgs/%@",strgroupID]];
    [rootRef keepSynced:YES];
    handlerLoadAllMsg = [rootRef observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeChildAdded withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot *snapshot)
                         {
                             if (snapshot.exists)
                             {
                                 [rootRef removeObserverWithHandle:handlerLoadAllMsg];
                             }
                         }]; 
}
```

Comment: do you have perf-mon in app? If not https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/get-started-ios should get you started to identify the response issue.. another problem is how your data node is structure... larger data within node is always an issue with network slowness

Comment: No, I don't have perf-Mon in my app. Can you please tell me how and where I can get it. My Node structure is not much larger. This same structure works on android perfectly.

Comment: link https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/get-started-ios

Comment: Thank you for giving me the link and also thankful for giving me the solution. If I used this solution what the benefit I can get here. Can you please explain me about it?

Comment: read introduction section in above link to understand how perf-mon is used..

Comment: I am implemented perf-mon. It only gives performance log here. still Didn't get a late response solution. Can you please help me with it?

Comment: update your question with response times from both ios as well as android and also add your android code in your question so that someone can take a look

Comment: @frank Van Puffelen Can you please help me? My Firebase Database too slow when data increase. I am using persistence for offline storage. offline data comes fast but updated data does not come fast. Can you please help me for the fast response from the database?